# Amazon Web Service EMR Pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

Just a simple question. When i create and run steps in an EMR cluster. When is the exact moment Amazon starts to charge. Does the fee include the cluster starting,  bootstrapping and terminating time?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question which should be asked of the Customer Service department for the company you are dealing with. Please see: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) and [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/).

Answer (score 1):

Billing commences when Amazon EMR starts running your cluster. You are only charged for the resources actually consumed. For example, let’s say you launched 100 Amazon EC2 Standard Small instances for an Amazon EMR cluster, where the Amazon EMR cost is an incremental $0.015 per hour. The Amazon EC2 instances will begin booting immediately, but they won’t necessarily all start at the same moment. Amazon EMR will track when each instance starts and will check it into the cluster so that it can accept processing tasks.

In the first 10 minutes after your launch request, Amazon EMR either starts your cluster (if all of your instances are available) or checks in as many instances as possible. Once the 10 minute mark has passed, Amazon EMR will start processing (and charging for) your cluster as soon as 90% of your requested instances are available. As the remaining 10% of your requested instances check in, Amazon EMR starts charging for those instances as well.

So, in the above example, if all 100 of your requested instances are available 10 minutes after you kick off a launch request, you’ll be charged $1.50 per hour (100 * $0.015) for as long as the cluster takes to complete. If only 90 of your requested instances were available at the 10 minute mark, you’d be charged $1.35 per hour (90 * $0.015) for as long as this was the number of instances running your cluster. When the remaining 10 instances checked in, you’d be charged $1.50 per hour (100 * $0.015) for as long as the balance of the cluster takes to complete.

Each cluster will run until one of the following occurs: you terminate the cluster with the TerminateJobFlows API call (or an equivalent tool), the cluster shuts itself down, or the cluster is terminated due to software or hardware failure. Partial instance hours consumed are billed as full hours.

Source - [EMR FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/faqs/)